# Get equations from string

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, string-parsing

I have a string in following pattern

```
( var1=:key1:'any_value including   space and 'quotes'' AND/OR var2=:key2:'any_value...' AND/OR var3=:key3:'any_value...' )
```

I want to get following result from this.

```
:key1:'any_value including   space and 'quotes''
:key2:'any_value...'
:key3:'any_value...'
```

Could any one please suggest the pattern/RE for the same ?

Failed attempts :

First I can split it by `AND/OR` and again split the further strings on `:` and so on, but looking for single RE/Pattern which can do this.

Comment: Are single quotes included ? Is `AND/OR` at end of each line ?

Comment: @noob yes for both...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex with negated pattern to match your data:

```
":[^:]+:'.*?'(?=\\s*(?:AND(?:/OR)?|\\)))"
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oZ7vJ6/3)

**Breakup:**

```
:                         # match a literal :
[^:]+                     # match 1 or more characters that are not :
:                         # match a literal :
'                         # match a literal '
.*?                       # match 0 or more of any characters (non-greedy)
'                         # match a literal '
(?=\s*(?:AND(?:/OR)?|\))) # lookahead to assert there is AND/OR at the end or closing )
```

Comment: Solves the purpose if value has no quotes !! Failed when value has quotes. for ex `( x = :bdate:'1992/12/22' AND x = :name:'John'O' )`

Comment: No, This is a sample data. please see first comment for real data.

Comment: So `AND/OR` is there at end of each line except the line just before closing `)`

Comment: Many thanks Anubhava, but compilation failed with invalid escape sequence error.

Comment: Java regex would be: `Pattern p = Pattern.compile( ":[^:]+:'.*'(?=\\s*(?:AND/OR|\\)))" );`

Comment: May be we need to escape '\s' as well. And for given input in comment 1 o/p is `:start_date:'1992/12/22' AND x = :end_date:'2016/04/11'`. Its still not splitted by AND/OR. (may be because all string is in one line, no new lines are there)

Comment: ok in that case try: `":[^:]+:'.*?'(?=\\s*(?:AND(?:/OR)?|\\)))"`

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work for your circumstances.
Unless you know parsing of quotes, there is not much else you could do.

Raw: `(?<==)(?:(?!\s*AND/OR).)+`
Quoted: `"(?<==)(?:(?!\\s*AND/OR).)+"`

Expanded:

```
 (?<= = )                  # A '=' behind
 (?:
      (?! \s* AND/OR )     # Not 'AND/OR' in front
      . 
 )+
```